# Exporting encrypted record to csv file from mysql table in PHP fails

Tags: php, mysql, php-openssl

I have a PHP page that select record from my SQL table and send an encrypted version of the record to CSV file. My problem is: when I select the record without using openssl encrypted, it export sucessfully, However, if I include the encrypte it opens a blank screen.

i hope will get a help here. Many Thanks in advance

```
This is my code:

  <?php

    // Database Connection
    require("xxx.php");
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'))
    $encryption_key = 'bRuD5WYw5wd0rdHR9yLlM6wt2vteuiniQBqE70nAuhU=';

     $result='select   *
            from encrypt';


            $file='grade/file'.date('YmdDH_i_s').'.csv';
            $qry = "select * from gb_centre where use_flag=1";
            $rs = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
            $getRowAssoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
    $query = (
        openssl_encrypt($result->uniqueid,'AES-256-CBC',$encryption_key,0,$iv),
        openssl_encrypt($result->username,'AES-256-CBC',$encryption_key,0,$iv),
    openssl_encrypt($result->shortname,'AES-256-CBC',$encryption_key,0,$iv),
    openssl_encrypt($result->rawgrade,'AES-256-CBC',$encryption_key,0,$iv),
    openssl_encrypt($result->finalgrade,'AES-256-CBC',$encryption_key,0,$iv),
    openssl_encrypt($result->cid,'AES-256-CBC',$encryption_key,0,$iv),
    openssl_encrypt($result->id,'AES-256-CBC',$encryption_key,0,$iv)

    );


    if (!$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error($con));
    }

    $users = array($uniqueid,$username,$shortname,$rawgrade,$finalgrade,$cid,$id);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $users[] = $row;
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$getRowAssoc['cid'].date('_Y-m-d_Hi').'.csv');
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputcsv($output, array('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5','a6','a7'));

    if (count($users) > 0) {
        foreach ($users as $row) {
            fputcsv($output, $row);
        }
    }

    ?>
```

**

### **EDIT**:

** 
I have edited the section of the code, it can now export the record to csv using the PHP OpenSSL and works fine, The problem is, it adds extra columns in the CSV file. I can't figure out where the error is.
Here is the edited code:

```
<?php
// Database Connection
require("config.php");
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
$key = 'bRuD5WYw5wd0rdHR9yLlM6wt2vteuiniQBqE70nAuhU=';
$encryption_key = 'bRuD5WYw5wd0rdHR9yLlM6wt2vteuiniQBqE70nAuhU=';
$string='select   *
        from encrypt'
$qry = "select * from gb_centre where use_flag=1";
        $rs = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
        $getRowAssoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
if (!$result = mysqli_query($con, $string)) {
    exit(mysqli_error($con));
}


if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $uniqueid[] = openssl_encrypt($row->uniqueid,'AES-256-CBC',$encryption_key,0,$iv);
    $username[] = openssl_encrypt($row->username,'AES-256-CBC',$encryption_key,0,$iv);
    $shortname[] = openssl_encrypt($row->shortname,'AES-256-CBC',$encryption_key,0,$iv);
    $rawgrade[] = openssl_encrypt($row->rawgrade,'AES-256-CBC',$encryption_key,0,$iv);
    $finalgrade[] = openssl_encrypt($row->finalgrade,'AES-256-CBC',$encryption_key,0,$iv);
    $cid[] = openssl_encrypt($row->cid,'AES-256-CBC',$encryption_key,0,$iv);
    $id[] = openssl_encrypt($row->id,'AES-256-CBC',$encryption_key,0,$iv);
    }
}
$users = array($uniqueid,$username,$shortname,$rawgrade,$finalgrade,$cid,$i);
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$getRowAssoc['cid'].date('_Y-m-d_Hi').'.csv');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, array('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5','a6','a7'));

if (count($users) > 0) {
    foreach ($users as $row1) {
        fputcsv($output, $row1);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: `$query` appears to be just a list of values and not an actual query.  You are also missing a `;` for `$iv`.  I would get a code editor that has a linter.  I recommend "Atom".  It's free and does a good job.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm trying to reference the $result query above in the $query. please, what am I doing wrong? Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are having a hard time with the fundamentals of executing queries.  I would just write some simple code to fetch and show the results of a single query.  Then when you get the idea you can add more to your code.

This is an example using prepared statements.  This will prevent sql injections.  You should learn how to use prepared statements for all of  your queries going forward.  Here is a link to a good resource that will teach you how to do any query you need to do properly.  Bookmark this link and refer to it often.  [MySQLi Prepared Statements](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection)

This code will print out the uniqueid from each row of the results returned from your query.

```
$query = "SELECT * 
FROM gb_centre 
WHERE use_flag = ?";

$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('i', 1); //set your bindings
$stmt->execute();
while ($result = $stmt->fetch_object()) {

  echo $result->uniqueid . '<br>';

}
```

Comment: I have amended the query but it still doesn't write the encrypted data on the CSV file, it only shows a blank page when the page is loaded. Any help on that, please.

Comment: The code I have above is meant to be run all by itself.  That way you can learn how to manage your queries and then build upon it.  You have errors in your code.  This will help simplify it so you can learn from it.